# Converting Parallels Desktop 7 VM from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, parallels

I have a Windows 2008 r2 x64 virtual machine that I run on my Mac through Parallels Desktop 7.

I need to convert this virtual machine so I can run it on my Windows 7 x64 machine. Which VM software should I use, and how do I convert my current VM?

I have been looking into Parallels Desktop 4 for Windows, VMware Workstation 8 and VirtualBox. Most of my VMs are used for developing and testing Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager.